# AudioRecording,Edting,Deleting,Playing

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-simulator

I am working on audio recording app.

Now I need to add a feature of editing the recorded audio file. The user should be able to play the audio file & insert recording into that. cut unwanted audio.

I need the two basic functionalit INSERT audio & overwrite existing audio.

Comment: What you have tried? Anyways read AVFoundation framework classes you will get all those things in it.

Answer (score 0):

please! check [iPhone with AVAudioRecorder (iOS 4)](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Recording_Audio_on_an_iPhone_with_AVAudioRecorder_%28iOS_4%29) may help you